# sql in database gives different result in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got the following sql:

```
SELECT COUNT(pu_id) FROM purchasing WHERE MONTH(pu_create_date)=MONTH(NOW())
```

In Mysql it gives the result 0 as expected.

When I put it in PHP I get the result 1 of $numMonth. This is the php code:

```
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$stmt= $db->query('SELECT COUNT(pu_id) FROM purchasing WHERE MONTH(pu_create_date)=MONTH(NOW())') ;
$numMonth = $stmt->execute();
echo $numMonth;
```

Why do I get two different results?

pu_id = unique key

pu_create_date = timestamp

Comment: You're not fetching the results of the query.

Comment: Are you using PDO or mysqli?

Comment: in this instance `1` is `true` as it is the `boolean` response from the `execute` method

Comment: Im using PDO for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to fetch the row from the query.

```
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$numMonth = $row[0];
echo $numMonth;
```